# Large memory usage while loading big json to firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, firefox

Wea re trying to build a client based application with html5 and indexeddb on Firefox 28. Large data are loading to firefox for the first time use with the format of json by AJAX requests. Each json resposnse is about 2MB (gzipped), data will be store to indexeddb with [IDBWrapper](https://github.com/jensarps/IDBWrapper).

The memory usage in firefox increased rapidly with responses. while we run about 12 responses the memory of firefox will grow to about 1GB (3GB total) and sometimes it will cause AJAX error. After success loading memory will drop direct to 500MB or below.

It seems that in the whole loading/storing process firefox don't have the chance to do GC, we've tried to use setTimeout between each response but it seems helpless.

My question is, is there any other way to reduce the memory usage of firefox while loading big json?

EDIT:
The code is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : URL['getData'],
    dataType : "json",
    data : {
        startDate : _startDate,
        endDate : _endDate,
        format : "json"
    },
    async : true,
    success : function(_data) {
        _data = null;
                // store to indexeddb
        _callback();
    },
    error : function() {
        setCurrentDataLabel('Error', 0);
    }
});
```

I remove the part of sotre to indexeddb to make is simple. It is funny that the memory also increased quickly. However if I change `dataType : "json"` to `dataType : "text"`, memory useage is much small and GC is running obviously. It seems firefox have some performance issue while handling json.

Comment: The best you can do is setting the variables to null as soon as you have to chance to to make the GC work, but if that doesn't solve a thing there's little you can do. You should perhaps question why you need to load that huge amount of data in the first place. Do you actually *need* to display all of that data?

Comment: That sounds pretty broken.  Is there any chance of a link to a page that shows this issue?  I'd like to see why GC is not happening here!

Comment: @MaxArt this is a buisness requirement, all data need to be stored locally for offline useage.

Comment: It's not sane to receive all that data at once. If you can't solve the memory issue, I'd recommend to send the data in smaller chunks, and progressively add the records as you receive each chunk.

Comment: storing data locally does not mean you have to keep it in memory... localStore or indexeddb is there for this.

Comment: You can implement pagination on server side to receive data in smaller chunks instead of receiving 2 MB data in 1 go.

Comment: Either do what `@Coder` said, or seeing that you control the client (you said it's a "corporate environment"), why not implement this a Firefox addon? You could then *stream* the data (constant, small memory size reads from the server) and store the data on the local disk (one chunk at a time). Whether or not the GC behaviour is "broken", there still may come a file-size that impossible to download and deserialise to memory in one go. BTW, you don't have to implement your entire SPA as an addon. You can plumb the privileged addon code into the window of your SPA via a non-privileged function.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh Your suggestion sounds resonable to me. Could you give more details on how to stream the data by firefox addon?

Comment: @SZhang how'd you go with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Server-side Pagination**

If the "server" in question is running some programming language/framework, and if you can easily make changes to the code running on that server, then the simplest approach would be what `@Coder` has alluded to in the comments. i.e: server-side pagination.

I'll leave `@Coder` to provide an answer for the "server pagination" case.

**Client-side Streaming**

On the other hand, if there's no code you can change on the server (e.g: it's a static JSON file that's produced by some other process, and there's only a simple static  HTTP server in place) then you might want to take the approach that I mentioned in the comments ie: having the *client* do the streaming.

In this approach:

1. You make a request to the server for the whole JSON file (whether that be 2MB or larger) -- instead of using `XMLHttpRequest` (AJAX), you use the native platform APIs in Firefox (`StreamListener`).
2. As data becomes available to read from the server, you use a so called JSON "Pull Parser" to parse the JSON text *incrementally* as it arrives.
3. You interpret the flow of parse "events" emitted by the pull parser in order to write the data incrementally to your local store (whether that be a database or file).

**NOTE 1:**

You can't use a GZIP encoding on the server side (explicitly or automatically) and still do streaming reads on the client. You'll either have to explicitly configure the server to only serve the JSON uncompressed, or instead you can simply use the `Accept-Encoding:` header to ask the server not to send you compressed content (ask for a non-existent compression scheme like `dont-compress-please`).

**NOTE 2:**

You can't do this kind of HTTP request (yet) from 'content' JavaScript (i.e: JavaScript content served by the web-server). You can only do this from 'privileged' JavaScript (e.g: inside a Firefox addon).

---

**Sandboxed HTTP requests**

I won't include an example of making the request itself (it's pretty big), but you can basically just cut & paste the first (simplest) example from the [Creating Sandboxed HTTP Connections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Creating_Sandboxed_HTTP_Connections) page on MDN.

In the example, in the `onDataAvailable` callback they just add the read text to a buffer (string) like this:

```
this.mData += scriptableInputStream.read(aLength);
```

Instead, you want to have your pull parser 'tokenize' *only* the newly read text and emit events for any fully parsed parts of the data read so far (and *not* build a string in memory representing the text read from the server).

**JSON Pull Parser**

A 'Pull parser' doesn't parse a string all at once (like say `JSON.parse`); instead ***you*** call its `tokenize()` method on ***each chunk*** of the source-text that you receive. The parser takes care of figuring out where it's up to in the input stream (using a "state machine") and when it begins or ends reading a so called 'atom' (for JSON e.g: start of an `Array`, a `Number`, end of an `Array`, start of an `Object`, etc) it will call a callback you supply (or emit an event) to tell you about it.

So in your case, say the JSON is basically an `Array` of `Object`s. You should basically ignore the 'start of `Array`' then for each 'end of `Object`' you write the data in single `Object` to your locale storage. That way, the biggest thing you've ever got in memory at one time is a single row/element from your larger file.

I found two JavaScript-based JSON Pull Parsers:

- [Benejson](https://github.com/codehero/benejson) + an [example for node.js](https://github.com/codehero/benejson/blob/master/javascript/nodetest.js) (easily adapted to StreamListener)
- [Clarinet](http://writings.nunojob.com/2011/12/clarinet-sax-based-evented-streaming-json-parser-in-javascript-for-the-browser-and-nodejs.html)

You need to configure the parser of your choice to "listen" to the appropriate starts/ends in your source-text.

***Privileged JavaScript***

As the `StreamListener` interface is privileged, if you still want this web-app to mostly run off the web (and just *have* an offline mode) then it will need to be implemented in a Firefox addon.

Additionally, as the Pull Parser is ***called*** by the `StreamListener` callback, it too will need to be implemented as privileged JavaScript inside the addon.

The easiest way to do both of those is to implement a [bootstrapped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) (a.k.a "restartless") Firefox addon which 'exports' the functionality you require 'into' your browser window so that your *unprivileged* 'content' JavaScript code can use it.

I've answered how to do this twice before (and there's a fair bit of code involved):

- [Expose File Writing to a Webpage with a Firefox Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843315/expose-file-writing-to-a-webpage-with-a-firefox-extension/21572638#21572638)
- [Calling JavaScript function defined in XUL from external IFRAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843315/expose-file-writing-to-a-webpage-with-a-firefox-extension/21572638#21572638)

Comment: oops, said XML several times instead of JSON. duh!

Comment: Really appreciated for your detailed solution! But in our condition if we change gzipped XMLHttpRequest to unzipped json file stream, we will meet network bandwith problem if we need to deploy to public internet (2MB vs 10MB for each request). However your answer is a very good solution to bypass json parsing directly in browsers.

Comment: from what I read here, it's possible in many browsers, unlike what you've said - http://oboejs.com/api#browser-support

Comment: @vsync You've misunderstood. While Oboe may indeed use the ability in (some) browsers to access the available part of an HTTP responseText before the download completes, it's still just an XMLHttpRequest -- that is, the whole responseText is still concatenated in memory (and then eventually swapfile) by your browser -- which is bad if the file is 2GB, say. Using privileged APIs from Firefox and others, you can *implement* the HTTP requestor interface itself, so instead of concatenating to the already downoaded data, you just *react* to it (pull-parse in OP's case).