# Get URL of selected tab from extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I have written a Firefox extension that requires the background document's URL. Normally, JavaScript's `document.URL` could achieve this - but this is different.

Please see my example below:

[image: shows the browser with several tabs opened and the extension panel displayed with a "fetch" button to alert the user to the current URL]

As can be seen, there are 4 tabs open:

- BBC Homepage
- Add-ons Manager
- Amazon.com
- Stack Overflow

And, the page currently being viewed is StackOverflow.com (*.. indeed*).

My question is: how can I retrieve the URL of the user's active window? (i.e. *http://www.stackoverflow.com*).

Below is the `panel.html` code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href=panel.css rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header><h3>Where aM I</h3></header>          
        This Mozilla extension will display the current <i>background</i> URL
    <main>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Click the Button</legend>
            <button onclick="PageViewing()">Fetch</button>
        </fieldset>
    </main>
    <script>
        function PageViewing() {
            alert(document.URL);
        }
    </script>
</body></html>
```

**EDIT**

If placed in the `main.js` file, this code snippet works:

```
    var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
    console.log("URL of active tab is " + tabs.activeTab.url); //yields SO.com
```

So in the context of my example, how could I retrieve it from P-Name/**lib**, for use in the P-Name/**data** directory - as a variable? 
[image: Terminal output showing files and directory structure]

Comment: You're going to have a hard time building your extension with an HTML user interface (rather than XUL). If you insist on doing so, you'll need to provide access to privileged JavaScript code from your non-privileged HTML DOM. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843315/expose-file-writing-to-a-webpage-with-a-firefox-extension/21572638#21572638 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843315/expose-file-writing-to-a-webpage-with-a-firefox-extension/21572638#21572638 for how to do so... [cont]

Comment: ... Those deal with HTTP served pages in `Browser` elements, but you could easily just take the 'install privileged method' parts from those posts and use them directly.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh (Regd. links) Is the "bootstrap.js" a user defined file, or are you maybe referring to "main.js"? My project was created using `cfx init`

Comment: I don't think I used the phrase "user defined". Your extension uses the addon-sdk. You've built the GUI for your extension using HTML (rather than using an XUL overlay). Because the HTML DOM is non-privileged, it can't directly run privileged functions. There's no simple way to do what you want. Either implement your GUI as an XUL overlay, or do amazing amounts of work to allow your privileged functions to be runnable from the HTML DOM (I provided two links on how to do so above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to establish a communication protocol between module and content script. This is done with `port`.

In your main.js

```js
panel.port.on('askactivetaburl', function(){
  panel.port.emit('sentactivetaburl', tabs.activeTab.url);
})
```

and in your panel script

```js
self.port.on('sentactivetaburl', function(activetaburl){
  // work with activetaburl
});

self.port.emit('askactivetaburl');
```